# Sens de « une saisie compréhensive » ？

Tags: sens

[image]

Voici encore une question du livre de Raymond Aron. Je voudrais savoir ce que signifie « une saisie compréhensive ».

Comment: « … une saisie par [la compréhension de] l'esprit, … » — *saisie* et *[com]préhension* ont la même racine (donc, tautologie !), mots féminins utilisés couramment pour ce qui concerne l'activité manuelle, plus rarement dans les domaines pédagogiques/didactiques liés aux mondes religieux, philosophiques, intellectuels

Comment: Saisie [TLF IA](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saisie) - *au figuré*. Compréhensive. [TLF IIA](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compr%C3%A9hensive).

Comment: Le savant veut **saisir le tout de chaque moment**. Saisie ici c'est ce qu'il saisit.

Comment: I tend to believe that it somehow relates when they say that you test will be comprehensive, covering almost all stuff.